# Python to Excel gives sharing violation

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Similar questions have been asked but none of the solutions such as using a with statement or writer.close()/writer.handles=None have solved the problem.

The below code works to output my data to an excel file. Everything is fine with it except if I try to edit the file and save it while Python is still open it gives me a "Sharing Violation" error. Python must still be accessing it in the background but I cant figure out how to close it completely. Any suggestions?

```py
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')

book = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_file)

writer.book = book
outputfile(writer, book, final_data, list_name[i], False, False, "C1", 2, "C", 16, 30, 12, "A","B")

outputfile(writer, book, df_transposed, sheetposed, True, False, "B2",1, "B", 20, 10, 10, "A","A")
        
writer.save()

writer.close

writer.handles = None
```

Comment: `writer.close` should be `writer.close()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually calling the `close` method, just accessing it.

```py
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="w")  # NB I use w

writer.close
# gives <bound method ExcelWriter.close of <pandas.io.excel._openpyxl.OpenpyxlWriter object at 0x10b96b2e0>>

write.close()
# actually closes the writer
```